# CSS transition on hover using BEM and Sass

Tags: css, sass, bem

I am trying to execute a CSS transition (`opacity:0` to `opacity:1` with pleasant transition) - I'm writing Sass and using BEM.

I was hoping to make use of the sibling operator `+` so that I can maintain my Sass nested BEM structure.

When the user hovers over `.price__text` I want to set the opacity of it's sibling element `.price__tooltip` to `1`

Here is my SCSS as an example

```
.price {
    &__text {
        [...]
    }
    &__tooltip {
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
        opacity: 0;
        [...]
        &+ .price__text:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that the last selector in the SCSS, `&+ .price__text:hover` would detect that when the sibling, `.price__text` has as `:hover` psuedo class it would make the current selected element `.price__tooltip` have `opacity:1` - but this doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
.price__tooltip {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
    [...]
}
.price__text:hover {
      &+.price__tooltip{
        opacity: 1;
      }
}
```

}

With this, the sibling .price__tooltip should get his opacity to 1 when .price__text is in hover state.